# can not move buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have a little problem that my buttons doesn't move when I am using a code that should move the button.

ViewControlle.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
```

ViewController.m:

```
@implementation GameViewController
@synthesize button1,button2;
```

code which should move the buttons:

```
button1.center=CGPointMake(button1.center.x, button1.center.y-10);
button2.center=CGPointMake(button2.center.x, button2.center.y+10);
```

why does the code not work or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: where do you call the moving code?

Comment: Have you correctly bound your IBOutlets ?

Comment: i don't think that does matter but I tried calling the code in the viewDidLoad to test it before i put it in its right place and Vinzzz that could be the stupidest fail anyone could do

Comment: @killerwakka did it work in your viewDidLoad? If so then it is obviously it's location that is preventing it from working. Also what is stupid for one person is tough for another. Some may even consider this question stupid so some humility is necessary, esp on a forum site like this.

Comment: well the strange thing is that it didn't work in the view DidLoad

Comment: don't know why but it won't work for me... but if i turn auto layout off it works. nt sure if it will work the same wit storyboards. Edit: also works with story board

Comment: @Floris497 Oh that makes sense. I just tested it and it worked great but I never use autolayout so that is probably why.

Comment: i personally hate auto layout, i don't get how it works and only irritates me. no idea why it there.

Comment: found out, autolayout isn't done when view did load gets called, instead place your code inside: `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {}` will aslo work with autolayout on

Comment: i hate that about javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because autolayout did not happen before view did load it will reset your locations.

when `- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called its done so place your code here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using AutoLayout for ViewController than It's not work.

Uncheck the AutoLayout for ViewController.